Blocker when adding a blob action in the logic app
The issue is gotten when adding a Blob action to the logic app to connect to Blob storage using system-managed identity.
Please refer to the screenshots below as well.

Can you explain the correct method to solve this problem?

Stupid question but have you configured the RBAC for the SMI?

Firstly, enable managed identity in Logic app:

You need to give access to Storage account with Storage Blob Data Contributor for Managed Identity like below:

then select and create:

Then you can use below design:


Then:

Output:


